# Problems issuing a Put method to an online database

Tags: java, android, http-put

I am trying to issue a Put on an online database that I have
here is my code

```
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar arg0, float arg1, boolean arg2)
{
    try
    {
    RatingBar rb = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_item);
    float currentRating = rb.getRating();
    float userRating = arg1;
    float count = getIntent().getIntExtra("count", 0);
    String newRating = String.valueOf(((currentRating*count)+userRating)/(count+1));
    rb.setRating(Float.valueOf(newRating));
    String url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("State") + "/collections/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("Activity") + "/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id")  +"?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPut putmethod = new HttpPut(url);

    putmethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    String content = "{ \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id") +"\"} , \"name\" : \"" + getIntent().getStringExtra("Name") + "\" , \"address\" : \"" + getIntent().getStringExtra("Address") +"\" , \"rating\" : \" " + newRating + "\" , \"count\" : \""+ String.valueOf(count+1) +"\" , \"coordinates\" : \" " + getIntent().getStringExtra("Coordinates") + "\" , \"img\" : \" "+ getIntent().getStringExtra("imgurl") +" \"}";
    putmethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(content,  HTTP.UTF_8));
    HttpResponse response = http.execute(putmethod);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()  == 200) 
        {
        Log.i("rating sent", "success");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Feedback submitted, Thank you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    else
    {
        Log.i("url", url);
        Log.i("rating sent", "failed");
        Log.i("response", String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
        Log.i("conent", content);

    }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Log.i("exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.i("exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.i("exception",e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

and here is the response I get from logcat

```
03-10 05:13:10.489: I/url(5686): https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/california/collections/Hiking/513c72fce4b07fcc2599c604?apiKey=G9Vr2_cykXY9AJvwe9NF_97R-onVVdFj
03-10 05:13:10.489: I/rating sent(5686): failed
03-10 05:13:10.489: I/response(5686): 415
03-10 05:13:10.499: I/conent(5686): { "_id" : { "$oid" : "513c72fce4b07fcc2599c604"} , "name" : "Test" , "address" : "Wild Cat Canyon Rd, El Cajon, CA 92021" , "rating" : " 2.5" , "count" : "1.0" , "coordinates" : " 32.911225,-116.821318" , "img" : " http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/j7B-K242DfWWFJfCxc7HQg/l.jpg "}
```

I know what the code 415 means, But I did include a header that specifically states that the content will be application/xml (I tried txt/xml too, it didn't work either)

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending XML in the body. The Content-Type should match the type you're actually sending. If you're sending JSON (as it appears) you should be setting application/json. If you are actually intending to send XML, you should be wrapping your data in XML entities.

Comment: Thanks!
I thought that response code 415 is specific for text/xml or application/xml.
Anyways thanks again

Comment: Not at all. It means that the content-type you're sending (xml) isn't accepted as a valid type on the URL you're putting to.